# Creating a solid with one side as a low poly randomized surface

Tags: modeling, mesh, fcurves

new to 3D modeling & Blender, hopefully I'm describing this in the correct way.

I'd like to take an arbitrary shape (I've been playing around with curves, eventually want to import an svg that describes the curve), give it thickness, then on the top face, create a low poly surface where the height of each vertex is at a random height.

My approach so far has been:

- Create a cube
- Select 4 corners that create one face of the cube
- Subdivide those until I get the right number of vertices
- Use Mesh -> Transform -> Randomize to create the low poly surface (I've also tried changing the "Fractal" parameter for my final subdivide, this seems to work well also)

Now, I'm wondering how to get my arbitrary shape out from this mesh. For a simple example, if I had a circle as my shape, I would be creating a cylinder, with the top of the cylinder the randomized low poly surface.

Is this the right approach even, or is there a different way I should do this, starting with the shape instead?